# How to get error messages in English on a foreign language version of Windows?

Tags: winapi

I am using a Dutch version of Windows and I have this piece of code:

```
::FormatMessage
(
  FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER
  | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM
  | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
  NULL,
  lastError,
  MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
  (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
  0,
  NULL
);
```

However, this returns the messages in Dutch. Would it possible to get the error messages in English instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid not! AFAIK, the English resources aren't available at all in other international editions of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of is to change the Operating System's configured language, which changes all text to said language.

I'm not sure if this is possible in Vista or 7 unless you have the Ultimate edition, which features 33-34 additional languages as downloads from Windows Update.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17469613/3240681) you could specify:

```
MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US)
```

for the 4th parameter of `FormatMessage`.

Or using [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24360415/3240681) you can set default user interface language for the current thread via [`SetThreadUILanguage`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd374053(v=vs.85).aspx).