# How to get boost::system::error_code::message in English?

Tags: winapi, boost, locale, boost-system

On Win7 having localized UI, `error_code::message()` returns a non-English message. As far as I see (in Boost 1.54, for `system_error_category`), the above function boils down to the following WinAPI call:

```
DWORD retval = ::FormatMessageA( 
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | 
    FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
    NULL,
    ev,
    MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), // Default language
    (LPSTR) &lpMsgBuf,
    0,
    NULL 
);
```

How to get the above `FormatMessage` to return an English message? I tried to set the locale, both with `std` functions and with `SetThreadLocale` - it didn't help.

**Update**: Just a clarification: essentially, my question is how to "override" programmatically the [user default language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373908%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and why setting locale is not enough.

Answer (score 4):

Been searching all over the internet for solution, and finally found [this](http://www.curlybrace.com/words/2008/06/10/setthreadlocale-and-setthreaduilanguage-for-localization-on-windows-xp-and-vista/).
Basically, you should call `SetThreadUILanguage` in your `main`/`WinMain`.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, you'll need to specify English for `dwLanguageId` instead of the default language. E.g.:

```
MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_DEFAULT)
```

or, if you want specifically US English:

```
MAKELANGID(LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US)
```

Note that this will fail if the message in the specified language is not present. So you may want to handle `ERROR_RESOURCE_LANG_NOT_FOUND` and try calling it again with `dwLanguageId=0`.

For more info, [see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679351).

Comment: As I mentioned, it's not my code, but Boost.System that calls `FormatMessage`.

Comment: Well, write your own function then. It's not difficult.

Comment: Patching Boost is an option, but I'd prefer a more clean solution. Actually, the question is whether it's possible to override (LANG_NEUTRAL,SUBLANG_DEFAULT), i.e. "User default language" (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373908(v=vs.85).aspx). Shouldn't thread locale or global locale affect it?