# C++ boost system::error_code language

Tags: c++, boost

i executed this code as TCP client:

```
        boost::system::error_code error;
        const std::string msg = "Hello from Client!\n";
        boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(msg), error);
        std::cout << "error.message(): " << error.message() << std::endl;
```

and got this message:
error.message(): ╬яхЁрЎш  єёях°эю чртхЁ°хэр

I use windows 10. Should i change language somewhere? Why it is not readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to insert `setlocale(0, "");` before printing the message;

Comment: That helps. Now i have message in readable russian language. Can i make this message on english?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465526/how-to-get-boostsystemerror-codemessage-in-english